# ¿Cómo puedo reutilizar un arreglo de caracteres en C para guardar una nueva cadena?

Tags: c

Creo el arreglo de la descripción de un producto, lo dejo en blanco porque más delante lo utilizaré:

```
char Desc[70];
```

Después de pedir claves a un usuario quiero asignar (ahora sí) una cadena a mi arreglo dependiendo de la clave:

```
if (strcmp(clave,"2SGL")==0)
{
    tarifa = 30.00;
    Desc[70]="Producto X";
}
```

El problema es que cuando quiero imprimir el arreglo con las descripción del producto no aparece nada de ella en pantalla. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código que compartes tiene un par de problemas, pero se reducen básicamente al mismo: así no es cómo se asigna un array/arreglo de caracteres.

Tal y como lo estás haciendo ahora mismo, por un lado defines un arreglo de caracteres de tamaño 70 (`char Desc[70];`), lo cual es correcto, pero después al hacer la asignación todo falla porque estás usando una notación incorrecta:

```
Desc[70]="Producto X";
```

Los corchetes con el tamaño del array sólo hacen en la declaración, no en las asignaciones. De lo contrario sólo estarías asignando el valor a esa posición en concreto en lugar de a la variable completa. Lo cual va a ser un problema en sí, porque estarías asignando a una posición de memoria que no le correspondería a la variable (70 está fuera de los índices permitidos: 0..69) lo cual puede generar resultados inesperados más adelante.

Para asignar una cadena como esa, podrías usar la función [`strncpy`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncpy.htm) que copiará una cadena a la variable especificada. Los parámetros de `strncpy` son la variable a la que quieres asignar el valor, la cadena que quieres asignar y el número de caracteres a copiar. Aplicado a tu código es:

```
if (strcmp(clave,"2SGL")==0)
{
    tarifa = 30.00;
    strncpy(Desc, "Producto X", 70);
}
```

Aquí puedes ver una [demo funcionando en OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/H1vyb_pYf).

Answer (score 4):

Ahondando un poco más en la respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro y dando detalles técnicos de cómo funcionan los *strings literales*.

Cuando en tu programa en C aparece un texto entrecomillado "Como este", (técnicamente denominado *string literal*), para el compilador el texto completo no es más que un número, normalmente de 32 bits.

Así pues, cuando tú hacías:

```
Desc[70] = "Producto X";
```

Básicamente es como si hubieras hecho:

```
Desc[70] = 0x50004008;
```

¿Cómo es eso?

Para ser más precisos, el compilador guarda en una parte del ejecutable todo el texto que hay entre comillas, y "toma nota" de en qué posición dentro del ejecutable está ese texto. Todos los textos que tenga tu programa "Entre comillas" se van recopilando uno tras otro en esa zona del ejecutable.

Cuando el programa entra en ejecución, es cargado del disco a la memoria por lo que todas los mensajes entrecomillados que usa tu programa irán a parar a zonas de memoria próximas. En el código que hacía uso de esos mensajes, en lugar del mensaje, lo que se usa es la dirección de memoria donde ha ido a parar ese mensaje en cuestión.

Un ejemplo. Supón que en una parte de tu código tienes algo como:

```
r = strcmp("uno", "dos");
```

El compliador, al ver la cadena `"uno"`, la codifica en Ascii y le añade un terminador (con lo que ocupa 4 bytes) y la deja en una cierta posición del ejecutable que está construyendo. Seguidamente hace lo mismo con la cadena `"dos"`, que irá a parar probablemente a continuación de la cadena anterior dentro del ejecutable. Con herramientas de inspección de ficheros binarios, podrías abrir un ejecutable y descubrir todas sus cadenas juntas, en la misma zona.

Cuando el programa se cargue en memoria, pongamos que la zona del ejecutable que contenía las cadenas es cargada a la dirección 0x50004000 de memoria. La primera cadena (`"uno"`) comenzará en esa dirección y ocupará 4 bytes. La siguiente cadena (`"dos"`) comenzará por tanto en la dirección 0x50004004.

Pues bien, la línea en que llamabas a `strcmp("uno", "dos")` es convertida a un código máquina que equivaldría a:

```
strcmp(0x50004000, 0x50004004);
```

Cada cadena entre comillas, es sustituída por el compilador por un número, que es la dirección de memoria en que la cadena estará almacenada en memoria cuando el programa se cargue. Es decir, cada cadena entrecomillada es en realidad **un puntero** al lugar donde está el texto.

Esta es la razón por la cual a cualquier función que espere un `char*`, se le puede pasar una cadena literal entre comillas.

Por eso funciona también como segundo parámetro de `strncpy(Desc, "Producto X", 70);`, y en ese caso la función hará una copia de la cadena del lugar donde está pre-almacenada a la dirección de la variable `Desc` (el 70 es el número *máximo* de caracteres a copiar, pero `strncpy()` se detendrá antes, cuando encuentre el terminador.

Volviendo a tu código:

```
Desc[70] = "Producto X"; // Equivale a Desc[70] = 0x50004008;
```

Estás metiendo un número en la posición 70 del array. Ya que ese número es típicamente de 32 bits, no cabrá en una posición del array (pues un `char` es de 8 bits). Naturalmente el compilador te habrá dado un *warning* en esa línea, pero si lo ignoras, probablemente guardará sólo la parte baja del dato (`08`) descartando el resto. En cualquier caso el problema no es sólo que estás accediendo a un elemento inválido del array, sino que además lo que estás guardando allí no es para nada lo que creías. No estás guardando el texto, sino la dirección donde está el texto (y mal, porque no cabe).

Comment: Buena respuesta y explicación.