# Error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast,

Tags: c, estructuras

Necesito su ayuda con esta pequeña parte de mi programa. Tengo que crear una base de datos de productos en Lenguaje C y una de las funciones que tenemos que usar se llama "inicializar.c", su propósito es inicializar el campo "producto" con ‘\0’ (el caracter null) para todos las entradas del arreglo info inv (arreglos del tipo struct). Al principio lo hice de esta manera:

```
/*Archivo del tipo .h (inv.h); contiene las librerías a utilizar en el 
programa y la estructura con sus campos a usar.*/
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Se crea la esctructura con los siguientes campos.
typedef struct{
       char producto[30];
       float coste;
       unsigned existencia;
}inv; 

 inv info_inv[100];
-------------------------------------------
 #include "inv.h"

 //Prototipos:
 FILE* mifopen(const char *, const char *);
 void* mimalloc(unsigned);
 unsigned menu1(void);
 unsigned menu2(void);
 void inicializar_lista(void);  

int main(){
    unsigned opc;
    //inv info_inv[100], *t_inv; 

   /*Realizamos un bucle indefinido para que el programa continue cuantas 
   veces el usuario desee. Luego, llamamos el menu principal (menu1.c).*/
   while(1){
        opc = menu1();

       if(opc == 1){
         //t_inv = &info_inv[100]; inicializar_lista(t_inv);     
         incializar_lista(void); 
      }
      else if(opc == 2){
         printf("\nVerificar: %u.\n",opc);
      }
      else {
         printf("\nERROR: Opcion NO mostrada en el Menu.\n");
         printf("\nSalida del programa.\nBye!\n"); break;  
      }


}
 system("PAUSE");   
 return 0;
}
--------------------------------------------------------
#include "inv.h"

//void inicializar_lista(inv *p){
void inicializar_lista(void){
     unsigned i;

     for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
         //p = &info_inv[i];
         //p->producto[0]="\0";
         info_inv[i].producto[0] = '\0';
     }    
 }
```

Cuando compile el programa me salió este error: [Warning]assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast. Y aún no veo por qué.
Las partes que aparecen comentadas fueron mis intentos en arreglar el problema, sin embargo, no funcionaron. 
Si me pueden ayudar con ello, se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como está el código que has adjuntado, contiene errores, pero no son el que planteas en la pregunta. Los errores son:

1. En el programa principal, llamas a `incializar_lista()`, en lugar de `inicializar_lista()`
2. Le pasas `void` como parámetro, lo que es incorrecto. Basta no pasarle nada.
3. La variable `info_inv` la declaras globalmente, pero al hacerlo en el fichero `.h`, esa declaración se estaría repitiendo en cada fichero `.c` que contenga un `#include "inv.h"`, lo que tampoco es correcto. Lo correcto es que la variable se declare globalmente sólo en un lugar (por ejemplo en el fichero donde está `main()`), y en los demás aparezca su declaración como externa (`extern inv info_inv[100]`). Esta declaración externa sí podría ir a `inv.h` para que todas las partes del programa sepan de la existencia de esa variable global, aunque realmente sólo se reserva sitio para ella en el módulo principal.

   Mejor aún sería que la variable no fuera global, sino local de `main()` y que se pasara como parámetro a las funciones que la necesiten. Parece que algo de eso intentaste en el código comentado, pero no está claro qué combinación concreta de código comentado fue la que probaste.
4. En `inv.h` debería ir declarado también el prototipo de la función `inicializar_lista()`, pues de lo contrario cuando la llamas desde `main()` el compilador no sabe si la estás llamando bien, con los parámetros correctos.

Como ves nada de esto está relacionado con el error que mencionas. De hecho, tras resolver estos errores, me compila sin errores ni Warnings (aunque no puedo construir el ejecutable por que falta la función `menu1()`)

El error que mencionas perfectamente podría estar causado por esta línea (que sin embargo no está en tu código, aunque en los comentarios veo cosas parecidas):

```
info_inv[i].producto[0] = "\0";
```

Como ves, he puesto comillas dobles alrededor del `\0`. Esto sí estaría mal pues en ese caso `"\0"` sería un *string literal*, que sería convertido por el compilador en una constante de tipo puntero (véase [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/148574/7123) a otra pregunta para más detalles sobre este tema).

En ese caso estarías tratando de meter un puntero en un `char` y podría darte un error similar al que comentas. Pero no es lo que tienes en tu código, en el que has usado `'\0'`, es decir, comillas simples en lugar de dobles, que es lo correcto porque en ese caso tenemos una constante de tipo `char`.

No sé si el código que pusiste es realmente el que estás probando. En todo caso, sería importante que señalaras qué línea en concreto te da el error para poder averiguar a qué se debe, ya que en mis experimentos, como dije, no conseguí replicar ese error.